# How do you set the expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources in Nginx

Tags: nginx, google-analytics, cache-control

---

### Leverage browser caching

---

**Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.**

```
https://www.google.com/…oad=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit (5 minutes)

https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js (20 minutes)

https://maps.googleapis.com/…=AIzaSyAy-BBHE1s92AY--7dxjbKCY5ZoLtUh7po (30 minutes)

https://www.google.com/jsapi (60 minutes)

https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```